# Dialog closes directly after open

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to show a dialog when an app is not in standalone mode. I have this code:

```js
$(document).on("pageinit", "#home", function (e) {
  console.log('pageinit');
  if (!window.navigator.standalone && (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    $.mobile.changePage('/mobile/install', {
        role: 'dialog',
        showLoadMsg: true,
        changeHash: false
    });
   }
});
```

The problem is that the dialog appears but close directly after and it returns to homepage.

The pageshow event for homepage happens twice.

How to prevent this behavior ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible to share a fiddle?

Comment: `pageshow`? you are binding `pageinit`...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bidou88/sLQ7G/

I want to show a dialog to explain how to add the weba app to homescreen. Is it the right way to do ? I have still a problem, the event click occurs two times on btn1

Comment: The button is getting bound twice to click, use `.off('click')` as in here http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/sLQ7G/1/

Comment: And btw, this is has nothing to do with your question here and in unaccepting my answer, since the code in my answer works well for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set delay using `setTimeout`.

```js
$(document).on("pageinit", "#home", function (e) {
 if (!window.navigator.standalone && (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $.mobile.changePage('/mobile/install', {
      role: 'dialog',
      showLoadMsg: true,
      changeHash: false
    });
  }, 100);
 }
});
```