# Unable to show config screen as dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an html file called config.html that lives in the same directory as my index.html.

The idea is to load my config on startup of my app and then pop the config screen if the config's not set. I then want to set the config and jump back so that the app continues to run normally.

Here is my method:

```
function _showConfig(callback) {
  jQuery.mobile.changePage("config.html", { transition: "pop" } );
}
```

When I run this, it executes this line, then appears to be loading the config screen up briefly before the whole thing vanishes.

Comment: SetTimeout to call the screen. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17762154/1771795 also, it should be, `$.mobile.chnagePage('File.html', { role: 'dialog', transition: 'pop' });`

Comment: @Omar I don't see a timeout option for changePage().